# How to communicate from android application to Patient monitoring System (PMS) in the form of packets by using Socket connection?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, android-wifi, serversocket, packets

We are having patient monitoring system which is Wi-Fi enabled. Here the requirement to establish a communication between android application and Patient Monitoring System (PMS) device using Socket connection and communication should be happen in the form of `packets`. Once initiate the request, it continuously sends the data over `Socket`, but I am unable to form the data in the form of packets.  Please can anyone help to how to send data in the form of data packets?

***The request format is given below.***
[image]

> **Header field** denotes the type of the operation that is to be performed.
>
> **Data payload** field contains two fields Length and Actual Data bytes.
>
> The Data **length** field indicates the number of bytes of data that
>   follow.
>
> The **Data Payload** field is optional.

***The header field is shown below :–*** 
[image]

> **1st bit** is direction of transfer. **0 – Read**, **1 – Write**.
>
> The **Command** field (7 bits) specifies the command to be executed.
>
> The **Option1** field will give the information about the parameter
>   that is under consideration.
>
> The **Option2** (lower 4 bits) and **Option3** (upper 4 bits) fields
>   are optional. For certain commands, they carry data with specific
>   meaning. For certain other commands, they are just ignored.

***Commands standards given below:-***
[image]

***Code snippet given below***

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#2D3238"
android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/connectBtn"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:onClick="onClick"
       android:text="Connect" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.test.pms.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.test.pms.app.R;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button connectBtn;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private String ipAddress = "192.168.1.55";
    private int portNumber = 4561;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isRunning = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    isRunning = false;
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.connectBtn:
            new CommunicateTask().execute();
            break;
    }
}

private class CommunicateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        sendData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}


private void sendData() {
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, portNumber);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                connectBtn.setText(getString(R.string.connected));
            }
        });
      /*  byte[] byteArray = new byte[5];
        byteArray[0] = (byte) 1;   //direction 0-write and 1- read
        byteArray[1] = (byte) 3;   // Command Type 3 - CMD_TIMESTAMP
        byteArray[2] = (byte) 1;   //Option1- SPO2
        byteArray[3] = (byte) 0;   //Option2: Nothing
        byteArray[4] = (byte) 1;   //Option3 : RED*/
        String command = "CMD_TIMESTAMP";
        //   byte arr[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(command);
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        //dataOutputStream.write(byteArray);
        //dataOutputStream.writeUTF(command);
        //   dataInputStream.write(arr);
        // dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello Server");
        while (isRunning) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                String b = dataInputStream.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (dataInputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here Socket connection is established successfully , but when I try read data from inputStream unable to read. Execution stopped at  `dataInputStream.readLine();`.

> **I tried multiple methods to read data from `InputStream` like**
>
> ```
> dataInputStream.readLine();
> dataInputStream.readByte();
> dataInputStream.read();
> ```

**Please can anyone help me to form request format in the form of packets and read the data in packets?**

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Is there any pairing protocol perhaps to authenticate the device or somehting like that? Also the header is clear but can you provide some detail on the other 2 bytes that add to the 5 bytes in the code?

Comment: Thanks for reply, there is no pairing protocol to authenticate. Can you guide me, how to form that header?

Comment: I am posting an aswer with how to set each byte of the header using hex notation. Besides of this, do you have any specification on the kind of packet.

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to set each byte of the header.

To form the header, you can set each byte using hex numbers.

For example:

```
byte b = 0xA8;

A == 10 == 0011 
8 == 8  == 1000

then b = A8 = 00111000;
```

Example:

Dir: 1
Command: 1010101 (just invented a command)

First byte is 11010101

We separate in two sets of four bits: 1101 0101 
Thse binaries reperesent 13 5 in decimal and D 5 in hex

The first byte value for this command is 0xD5

Comment: Thanks, let me try. How to read continuous data from inputStream. If you help on this, it would be helpful to us.

Comment: To do that you just read() the inputStream while the read value is different that -1. If is continious you will have to do it in a backgroud thread or in a Service.